# How do you save this form data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Here is my forms.py:

```
class MatchingForm(forms.Form):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MatchingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for matchq in MatchQuestions.objects.all():

            self.fields[matchq.question] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Choice.objects.filter(question=matchq.id))
            self.fields[matchq.howImportant] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((1,"Very Important"),(2,"Not Important"),))
```

As you can see, this form iterates through data in my database. How can I iterate through these dynamic form fields in my view so that it saves each to each? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to overwrite the save method of your form, and iterate cleaned_data

```
class MatchingForm(forms.Form):

    [...]

    def save(self):
        for question, howImportant in self.cleaned_data.items():

             obj, created = MatchQuestions.objects.get_or_create(question=question, 
                                                          howImportant=howImportant)
```

PD: This is an example, because I don't know your data models.